# Как отличить союз от союзного слова?

Tags: синтаксис, спп, союзы

Как отличать? И может ли выступать союзное слово в роли подлежащего или другого члена предложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве **дополнения**

Иногда, даже зная все правила,  не так просто отличить союз от союзного слова, например:

Он сказал, что он знает о случившемся (союз, СПП с придаточным изъяснительным). Он сказал, чтО он знает о случившемся ( союзное слово, СПП с придаточным изъяснительным).

Он приехал, когда все уже спали (союз, СПП с придаточным времени). Это было время (какое?), когда все уже спали (СПП с придаточным определительным, союзное слово).

.

Comment: Простите, но не вижу, что Ваше дополнение внесло ясность. Правила-то всё же применять надо. Союз можно заменить союзом, с. слово местоимением или наречием. В придаточном определительном  когда (куда, где, что и др.) будет союзным словом, потому что  местоимённое слово можно заменить местоимением который (в главном будет указательное местоимение, или его можно предположить: Это было время (какое?)(такое), когда( в которое) все уже спали ),  если же слово можно заменить другим союзом (в то время как), то это союз: Он приехал (когда?), когда (в то время как) все уже спали

Comment: Моё дополнение говорит ТОЛЬКО о том, что в сложных случаях  для правильного решения важно определить вид предложения.  А вообще говоря, как мне кажется,  по этой теме нужно знать даже не правила, а информацию: а) виды придаточных; б) способы связи , применяемые для каждого вида (местоименная, союзная или местоименно-союзная); в) определение для союза и союзного слова. Этого достаточно для анализа СПП, а правила, подстановки, замены - это скорее инструменты для формального, а не грамматического  решения задачи. Опять же повторюсь, что это мое личное мнение.

Answer (score 4):

Союз — это **служебная** часть речи, которая **служит для связи** частей сложного предложения, однородных членов предложения и целых предложений. **Не является самостоятельным членом предложения**

Союзные слова — это местоименные слова, в которых совмещены свойства самостоятельной (знаменательной) и служебной части речи. В качестве союзных слов способны употребляться только местоименные слова вопросительного типа:
местоимения-существительные (кто, что);
местоименные прилагательные (какой, который, каковой, каков, кой, чей);
местоименные наречия (где, куда, откуда, когда, как, насколько, почему, отчего, зачем);
местоименное числительное (сколько).

**Союзное слово является членом предложения** и служит для присоединения придаточного к главному предложению в СПП

*Я знаю, что скоро уеду*. Что — союз.

*Я знаю, **что** мне теперь делать*. Делать (что?). Что — союзное слово —  местоимение, является дополнением.

*Я радуюсь, когда вижу тебя.* Когда — союз.

*Я объяснил, **когда** нужно приехать*. Приехать (когда?). Когда —  обстоятельство времени, союзное слово.

*Он услышал стихотворение, которое ему  так нравится*. Которое — подлежащее, союзное слово.

Answer (score 0):

В сложноподчинённом предложении главная часть связывается с придаточной частью с помощью следующих средств связи:
подчинительных союзов,
союзных слов,
указательных слов.

Союз — это служебная часть речи, которая служит для связи частей сложного предложения, однородных членов предложения и целых предложений.

Союзные слова — это местоименные слова, в которых совмещены свойства самостоятельной (знаменательной) и служебной части речи. В качестве союзных слов способны употребляться только местоименные слова вопросительного типа:
местоимения-существительные (кто, что) ;
местоименные прилагательные (какой, который, какой, каков, кой, чей) ;
местоименные наречия (где, куда, откуда, когда, как, насколько, почему, отчего, зачем) ;
местоименное числительное (сколько).

Указательные слова находятся в главном предложении (бывают не всегда!). Это указательные местоимения и наречия тот, такой, столько, там, туда, тогда и др., которые указывают, что при нём имеется придаточное предложение, и выделяют его содержание: То сердце не научится любить, которое устало ненавидеть (Некрасов) ; Там, где растут розы, растут и шипы (пословица).

Основная проблема при анализе сложноподчинённого предложения — трудности в разграничении союзов и союзных слов.

Чтобы отличить союз от союзного слова, нужно средство связи частей сложноподчинённого предложения проверить по следующим признакам.

Союзы
Союзные слова

1. Не являются членами предложения: Он сказал, что сестра не вернётся к ужину (что — союз, не является членом предложения) .
2. Являются членами придаточного предложения: Она не сводила глаз с дороги, что ведёт через рощу (союзное слово что — подлежащее) .
3. Часто (но не всегда! ) союз можно изъять из придаточного предложения, ср. : Он сказал, что сестра не вернётся к ужину. — Он сказал: сестра не вернётся к ужину.
4. Поскольку союзное слово — член придаточного предложения, его нельзя изъять без изменения смысла: Она не сводила глаз с дороги, что ведёт через рощу; невозможно: Она не сводила глаз с дороги, ведёт через рощу.
5. На союз не может падать логическое ударение.
6. На союзное слово может падать логическое ударение: Я знаю, что он будет делать завтра.
7. После союза нельзя поставить частицы же, именно.
8. После союзного слова можно поставить частицы же, именно, ср. : Я знаю, что же он будет делать завтра; Я знаю, что именно он будет делать завтра.
9. Союз нельзя заменить указательным местоимением или местоименным наречием.
10. Союзное слово можно заменить указательным местоимением или местоименным наречием, ср. : Я знаю, что он будет делать завтра. — Я знаю: это он будет делать завтра; Я знаю, где он был вчера. — Я знаю: там он был вчера.

Необходимо помнить, что не каждый из этих приемов в отдельности может помочь распознаванию союза и союзного слова. Ни один из признаков не является универсальным, т. к. опирается лишь на внешнее выражение существенных внутренних различий. Используя названные критерии в совокупности или в различных сочетаниях, можно научиться определять, союзом или союзным словом присоединяется придаточная часть к главной.

Помимо указанных выше способов разграничения союзов и союзных слов следует учитывать следующее:

1. Что, как, когда могут быть как союзами, так и союзными словами. Это омонимы, поэтому при разборе сложноподчинённых предложений с этими словами надо быть особенно внимательными.
   Когда является союзом

— в придаточном времени (Отец мой скончался, когда мне был шестнадцатый год. Лесков) ;

— в придаточном условия (Когда нужно чёрта, так и ступай к чёрту! Гоголь) .
Когда является союзным словом

— в придаточном времени, если в главной части есть указательное слово тогда (Отец мой скончался тогда, когда мне был шестнадцатый год) ;

— в придаточном изъяснительном (Я знаю, когда он вернётся) ;

— в придаточном определительном (Тот день, когда мы встретились впервые, я не забуду никогда; когда в определительном пр